# Earth Engine: different results with "covariance" and "centeredCovariance" on de-meaned data?

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

I am trying to compute a covariance matrix in earth engine. EE offers two reducers:

1. `ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance`
2. `ee.Reducer.covariance`.

My understanding is that `ee.Reducer.covariance` on the raw data should be the same as `ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance` on a band-demeaned data (from help file: *this reducer requires that the data has been mean centered*.) This is also suggested in this EE [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f80ead7606e2feeaa3744cf3d03d761d), which is mentioned on the official documentation ([eigen anaysis](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/arrays_eigen_analysis)). However, computing both approaches in the same script leads to quite different results!?

How to explain these different results? Is my expectation that the two should the same wrong, did I make a mistake in the code, or is there a problem in the way `ee.Reducer.covariance` is computed (using apparently this [algorithm](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/205797606.pdf))? Note that there might be a difference in the degrees of freedom adjustment (1/N vs 1/(N-1)) but with 1896290 pixels in the zone, this difference ratio is at most 1.000001, while difference ratio in the results is easily 1.122402!

Code ([link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1a0aa5f2a4cd4a59a52271c695f35474)):

```
// Script mainly copy-pasted from https://code.earthengine.google.com/f80ead7606e2feeaa3744cf3d03d761d, 
//which is mentioned on https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/arrays_eigen_analysis


// Load a landsat 8 image, select the bands of interest.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T/LC80440342014077LGN00')
  .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11']);

// Display the input imagery and the region in which to do the PCA.
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-122.77, 37.70], [-122.77, 37.44],[-122.10, 37.44],[-122.10, 37.70]]], null, false);
Map.centerObject(region, 10);
Map.addLayer(ee.Image().paint(region, 0, 2), {}, 'Region');
Map.addLayer(image.clip(region), {bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 20000}, 'Original Image');

// Set some information about the input to be used later.
var scale = 30;
var bandNames = image.bandNames();

// Mean center the data 
var meanDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9
});

var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
var centered = image.subtract(means);


// Compute the covariance of the bands within the region.
var covar_cent = centered.toArray().reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });


var covar = image.toArray().reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.covariance(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });



print(ee.Array(covar_cent.get('array')).slice(1, 0, 1))
print(ee.Array(covar.get('array')).slice(1, 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I received a response on the GEE google groups list, basically the problem arises because I am computing this over a very large zone, leading to numerical instability. Using instead a much smaller zone leads to nearly identical results. See for example this [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/31c2342747dafd9dc63594fac39cd2cd).

In general it seems the two-step approach to first centering then using `ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance()` to be preferred to the direct `ee.Reducer.covariance()`.